# Returning PHP Multi-Dimension Array to Javascript/AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

My understanding is that in order to return a complex PHP variable to Javascript, it should be done via AJAX and json_encode.  Could somebody give me an actual example (both PHP and Javascript code) of this?  Lets say we have the two-dim array in PHP:

```
$twoDArr = array( array('Greg', 44, 'Owner'),
                  array('Joe', 23, 'Renter'),
                  array('Susan', 39, 'Owner'),
                  array('John', 32, 'Renter)
                );
```

How would we return this to an analogous two dimensional array in javascript using json_encode?

Comment: Uh... you mean other than the calls to `json_encode()` and `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Uh, I don't know.  My experience is pretty limited with all of this stuff.  That's why I'd like to see some examples.  If you know some simple examples then feel free to post them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$twoDArr = array( array('Greg', 44, 'Owner'),
                  array('Joe', 23, 'Renter'),
                  array('Susan', 39, 'Owner'),
                  array('John', 32, 'Renter)
                );
?>

<script>
twoDArr = JSON.parse(<?=json_encode($twoDArr)?>)
alert(twoDArr[0][0]) //alerts 'Greg'
alert(twoDArr[0][1]) //alerts '44'
alert(twoDArr[1][0]) //alerts 'Joe'
</script>
```

Comment: While this example certainly works, it is generally best to avoid eval when a simple alternative is present.  In this case, you could replace the eval statement with JSON.parse(<?=json_encode($twoDArr)?>) to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Sorry for being so obtuse...you have "JSON.parse(<?=json_encode($twoDArr)?>)"  What's with the "?=" is that some sort of shorthand?  I tried this in my sample page and I get nothing coming back.

Comment: Something weird is up...if I echo out json_encode($twoDArr) I get:

[["Greg",44,"Owner"],["Joe",23,"Renter"],["Susan",39,"Owner"],["John",32,"Renter"]] 
That isn't right is it?  Should the arrays be separated by a ":"?

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem.  I'm not sure why, but the php variable has to be double encoded with JSON_ENCODE.  So the JSON.parse line should read:
   var twoDArr=JSON.parse(<?php echo JSON_ENCODE(JSON_ENCODE($twoDArr))?>);

Answer (score 0):

Your program would of ran in a more simpler way like this:

```
        <?php

            $twoDArr = array( array('Greg', 44, 'Owner'),
                              array('Joe', 23, 'Renter'),
                              array('Susan', 39, 'Owner'),
                              array('John', 32, 'Renter)
                            );
        ?>

        <script>
            var twoDArr = <?php echo json_encode($twoDArr); ?>;
            alert(twoDArr[0][0]) //alerts 'Greg'
            alert(twoDArr[0][1]) //alerts '44'
            alert(twoDArr[1][0]) //alerts 'Joe'
        </script>
```