# How do you encode a two dimensional PHP array as a JSON array to be decoded within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have an array of arrays in php called `$searchResults`. Each array within `$searchResults` is formatted as such:

```
array('name' => <name> , 'value' => <value>)
```

I want to encode this two dimension array as a JSON array and pass it back to my JavaScript. How can I encode this array in PHP such that I can decode it in JavaScript and then iterate through each array by key? Is this even possible? I have found examples of encoding multidimensional arrays that don't use the `<key> => <value>` syntax but I am not really sure if these are applicable. An example would be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986627/returning-php-multi-dimension-array-to-javascript-ajax). Thanks!

Comment: Can you use json_encode? IE: `printf( "<script>var jsvar = %s;</script>", json_encode( $searchResults ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:

1) Pass array in current state:

```
<?php
$array = [
    [ 'name' => 'x' , 'value' => 1 ],
    [ 'name' => 'y' , 'value' => 2 ],
    [ 'name' => 'z' , 'value' => 3 ]
];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var php_json = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

for(var i = 0; i < php_json.length; i++){
    console.log(php_json[i]);
}
</script>
```

2) Convert to key-value pairs and pass:

```
<?php
$array = [
    [ 'name' => 'x' , 'value' => 1 ],
    [ 'name' => 'y' , 'value' => 2 ],
    [ 'name' => 'z' , 'value' => 3 ]
];

$buffer = [];

foreach($array as &$nested){
    $buffer[$nested['name']] = $nested['value'];
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var php_json = <?php echo json_encode($buffer); ?>;

for(var key in php_json){
     console.log(key, php_json[key]);
     //       key ^      ^ value
}
</script>
```

You can easily pass any simple php data structure to javascript via using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json-encode) function.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my templates:

```
<script>window.bootstrapped_data = <?php echo json_encode($my_js_vars); ?>;</script>
```

Rendered output will look like this:

```
<script>window.bootstrapped_data = {"name":"<name>","value":"<value"};</script>
```

Replace `$my_js_vars` with your variable name, and called the JavaScript variable whatever you want. You can then access this variable normally in JavaScript.

Don't let [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) throw you off, PHP will render a valid JavaScript object.